# Rudin's RCA theorem $2.24$ Lusin's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

There are the definitions which we need for the proof of the theorem:
[image]

[image]

[image]

There is the theorem:
Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu(A)$ $\lt$ $\infty$, $f(x)$ $=$ $0$ if $x$ $\notin$ $A$, and $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$. Then there exists a $g$ $\in$ $C_c(X)$ such that $\mu$ ({$x:f(x)\neq g(x)$}) $\lt$ $\epsilon$.

Furthermore, we may arrange it so that

$sup$ $x \in X$ $|g(x)|$ $\leq$ $sup$ $x\in X$ $|f(x)|$.

There is the proof:

Assume first that $0$ $\leq$ $f$ $\lt$ $1$ and that $A$ is compact.

Attach a sequence ${s_n}$ to $f$, as in the proof of Theorem $1.17$, and put $t_1$ $=$ $s_1$ and $t_n$ $=$ $s_n$ $-$ $s_{n-1}$ for $n$ $=$ $2$,$3$,$4$,...

Then $2^n$$t_n$ is the characteristic function of set $T_n$ $\subset$ $A$, and

$f(x)$ $=$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $t_n(x)$   ($x$ $\in$ $X$).

I don't understand why is $2^n$$t_n$ the characteristic function of a set $T_n$ $\subset$ $A$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For $n\ge2$ and for any $y\in[0,n-1),$
  $$2^n(\varphi_n-\varphi_{n-1})(y)=\lfloor2^ny\rfloor-2\lfloor2^{n-1}y\rfloor\in\{0,1\},$$
  in particular $2^n(\varphi_n-\varphi_{n-1})(0)=0$ and for any $y\in[0,1),$ $2^n(\varphi_n-\varphi_{n-1})(y)\in\{0,1\}.$
  Since $t_n=(\varphi_n-\varphi_{n-1})\circ f$ and $0\le f<1$ and $f=0$ outside $A,$ the result follows.
- The proof for $n=1$ is similar: for any $y\in[0,1),$
  $$2\varphi_1(y)=\lfloor2y\rfloor\in\{0,1\},$$
  in particular $2\varphi_1(0)=0.$
  Since $t_1=\varphi_1\circ f$ and $0\le f<1$ and $f=0$ outside $A,$ the result follows.

Comment: how did you get [$2^n y$] - $2[2^{n-1} y ]$ ?

Comment: If $0\le y<n,$ $\varphi_n(y)=\delta_n\lfloor y/\delta_n\rfloor,$ where $\delta_n=2^{-n}.$

Comment: do you mean floor function in this [] brackets?

Comment: Yes, $\lfloor \rfloor$ (not []) is a usual notation for the floor function and corresponds to Rudin's definition of $k_n(t)$: the unique integer $k$ such that $k\delta_n\le t<(k+1)\delta_n$ is  $\lfloor t/\delta_n\rfloor.$

Comment: I’ve few more questions about it . But I’ve to sleep now. I will ask u tommorow and then i will accept ur answer ok?

Comment: Ok, good night.

Comment: Yes there is 03:28 am

Comment: sorry for replying too late. I was very busy. you've said that For $n\ge2$ and for any $y\in[0,n-1),$
$$2^n(\varphi_n-\varphi_{n-1})(y)=\lfloor2^ny\rfloor-2\lfloor2^{n-1}y\rfloor\in\{0,1\},$$  . Even tho $f$ $=$ $0$ outside $A$ , we still could get that characteristic function $2^n t_n$ $=$ $0$ inside $A$. So we should remove points where characteristic function becomes $0$ inside $A$ and that will be called $T_n$, right?

Comment: Yes, any function $f$ with values in $\{0,1\}$ is the characteristic function of $T:=f^{-1}(\{1\}),$ and if $f$ is $0$ outside of some set $B,$ then that $T$ is contained in $B.$